# Pycairo scale distortion

Tags: python, scale, cairo, scaletransform, pycairo

I am struggling to draw a circle onto a rectangular png background. Whenever I try to draw a circle, it is stretched according to the scale of my image--making it an ellipse instead of a circle.

Here is the set up:

```
#set background image
surface = cairo.ImageSurface.create_from_png (image)
context = cairo.Context (surface)

WIDTH = cairo.ImageSurface.get_width(surface)
HEIGHT = cairo.ImageSurface.get_height(surface)
context.scale (WIDTH, HEIGHT)
```

And here is the circle drawing function, (x coord, y coord, radius, color value) and functions used for positioning:

```
def draw_node(cx,cy,r, rgb):
  context.arc(x_scale(cx), y_scale(cy), r, 0, 2 * math.pi)
  context.set_source_rgb(rgb[0]/255.0,rgb[1]/255.0,rgb[2]/255.0)
  context.fill()
  context.stroke()

def x_scale (x):
  width = 1000.0
  return (x + .5) / width

def y_scale (y):
  height = 1000.0 * HEIGHT / WIDTH
  return (y + .5) / height
```

I would particularly appreciate any advice on how to resolve the systemic scaling issue, but I would also appreciate advice on how to draw a circle within the confines of my existing setup.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

there is probably no way to avoid that `context.arc` will draw an ellipse when your scaling is not symmetric. with your `x_scale (x)` function you only scale the center of the circle to be where it should be.

as a workaround i'd suggest to scale both directions by the same amount; sacrifice therefore that `x_max` and `y_max` will  both be equal to `1`.

i'd change in your code:

```
context.scale(HEIGHT, HEIGHT)
print('surface = 1 x {:1.2f}'.format(WIDTH/HEIGHT))

def draw_node(cx,cy,r, rgb):
  context.arc(cx, cy, r, 0, 2 * math.pi)
  context.set_source_rgb(rgb[0]/255.0,rgb[1]/255.0,rgb[2]/255.0)
  context.fill()
  context.stroke()
```

and not do any scalings (or scale by `1000` if that's what you prefer).